# listing unsecured shared folders on windows

Tags: c#, active-directory

```
//ActiveDirectorySearch1
//Displays all computer names in an Active Directory
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ActiveDirectorySearch1
{
    class Class1
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://pune");
           DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
           mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
           Console.WriteLine("Listing of computers in the Active Directory");
           Console.WriteLine("============================================");                            

           foreach(SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.ToString()); }
               Console.WriteLine("=========== End of Listing =============");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

now i just want to list all unsecured shared folders ..what do i do ?

Answer (score 1):

If your AD is pre Windows Server 2008, you should really change your filter to (&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)). This will take advantage of indices in the database and be much more efficient.

As to getting Shares, I've used [Win32_Share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28VS.85%29.aspx) before. You can use [mgmtclassgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa%28VS.80%29.aspx) to build a strongly typed wrapper that's pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Actually i want shared folders on all remote computers on network..i guess this cannot be done using WMI without administrative priveledges.

Comment: I am trying to use net32api.dll ...pls help