# how to get the shared folder for a given server in .net

Tags: .net, shared-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [listing unsecured shared folders on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694786/listing-unsecured-shared-folders-on-windows)

I want to know how to get the shared folders by a given server name on window platform.

I mean when user submit the server name "\server"

I want to list the shared folders.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `NetShareEnum` from the win32 api. There is some [documentation for it here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netshareenum.html)

You could also take a look at [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths).

Comment: I read the article yet,however I can not find the class `ShareCollection`

Comment: @hguser i've not used this stuff myself, but looking at the codeproject article, if you download the source files, there is a file called `Shares.cs` that contains a class called `ShareCollection`. Is that what you need. That article appears to be a .net wrapper around `NetShareEnum`.